# WebStorm - temporary files and unable to see any changes

Tags: webstorm

Next to my html and scss codes of the frontpage, `jb_temp` files keep generating. I've tried deleting them but nothing happens. I've tried disabling safe write and both my html and css files became completely blank (undo unsolved it).

Since these files have been here, I haven't managed to make any changes to my webpage. It does compile, but I can't see the new result, only what I wrote a day ago.

I'm wondering if anyone has the same issue and/or how I can solve it.

Comment: `jb_temp` are created by that "safe write" option. If it stays there ... then it must be file permission issue -- you should investigate that. Also check `idea.log` file (Help | Show Log in...) for any hints (related exceptions etc)

Comment: Thank you. I got an error (a bit late, though). I was unable to save, restarting solved the issue.